# Give an example of an element of infinite order in SO(2;R)

Tags: matrices, group-theory, orthogonal-matrices

I want a matrix in $SO_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ that has determinant equal to +1 and is orthogonal but has infinite order so: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} $ when $A \in SO_{2}(\mathbb{R}): A ^{n} \neq id$ where

id =
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
I can't find such a matrix can anyone give me an example?

Comment: Hint: Geometrically, what are elements of $\mathrm{SO}_2(\mathbb R)$, as linear maps?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements of $\operatorname{SO}_2(\mathbb{R})$ are rotations. Any rotation by an angle that is not a rational multiple of $\pi$ will work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a prime number $p\ge5$. Then *most likely* the matrix below
$$\pmatrix{\displaystyle\frac1p & -\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{p^2-1}}p\cr \strut \displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{p^2-1}}p &\displaystyle \frac1p\cr}$$
for some prime should work. This is orthogonal and det = 1. I  hope (no proof!) that $\cos\pi x$ for rational values of $x$ will miss out some $\frac1p$.